# Displaying Grouped List Items Inline

Tags: views, theming

Hello i was hoping to create a list view that would look something like this-

FOOTBALL TEAM A
football team a link one - football team a link two - football team a link three

FOOTBALL TEAM B
football team b link one - football team b link two - football team b link three

etc etc

I have created a view and have it grouped by team. Everything works well. Its just the links below it are also vertical and not horizontal. You can view it here-
http://onlinebanter.com/football/links

Ive tried various bits of  display:inline aound the view but i just cant seem to find the place that works. Could anyone advise me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add css to your theme css file and clear cache to see the effect...

I am not a css guy, but below css code should work...

```
.view-footballlinks .item-list ul li {
  float:right;
}
```

Try, and let us know...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the *Multiple Field Settings* in Views? Or is it necessary for the items to be in an actual html list?

With that you can specify a '–' as a separator between your links.

[image: Image of views settings - Multiple Field Settings]

Comment: thanks hampusn. im on d6 and it seems to be differant. I have tried what is the equivilent i think and that just keeps the fields in a line. It wont put the individual links horizontal. thanks though

Comment: No it would seem as if the separator was introduced in Drupal 7.